# Correct way to recreate HTML document from a string?

Tags: php, javascript, html, encryption, greasemonkey

First things first, I'm cheap! :) I can't afford to buy a static IP for my domain and I can't afford those fancy certificates...  So no SSL/HTTPS for me.

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to roll-out my own "HTTP encryption". Here's what I have accomplished so far:

1. Modified an existing proxy script (Glype/PHProxy) to "encrypt" (base64 for now) the echo output. (I'm wrapping the entire content in a body element, btw)
2. Written a GreaseMonkey script to "decrypt" the encrypted output.

The thing works on simple websites. But when I'm loading complex websites (like a browser game), the javascripts are broken (btw, the script can render the game perfectly when I turned off my encryption).

Upon inspection via FireBug, I've noticed that the contents of the head element is being placed in the body element. This doesn't always happen so I suspected that the PHP is throwing malformed output, but I decoded the base64 using an offline tool and the HTML looks okay.

Here's a sample output from the PHP:

```
<html><body>PGh0bWw+DQo8aGVhZD4NCjx0aXRsZT5IZWxsbzwvdGl0bGU+DQo8L2hlYWQ+DQo8Ym9keT4NCjxoMT5IZWxsbyBXb3JsZDwvaDE+DQo8L2JvZHk+DQo8L2h0bWw+</body></html>
```

Here's the decoded HTML from Firebug (after being processed by the GM script):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my GM script to decode the PHP output:

```
function utf8_decode (str_data) {
    var tmp_arr = [],
        i = 0,
        ac = 0,
        c1 = 0,
        c2 = 0,
        c3 = 0;

    str_data += '';

    while (i < str_data.length) {
        c1 = str_data.charCodeAt(i);
        if (c1 < 128) {
            tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(c1);
            i++;
        } else if (c1 > 191 && c1 < 224) {
            c2 = str_data.charCodeAt(i + 1);
            tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(((c1 & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
            i += 2;
        } else {
            c2 = str_data.charCodeAt(i + 1);
            c3 = str_data.charCodeAt(i + 2);
            tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(((c1 & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
            i += 3;
        }
    }

    return tmp_arr.join('');
}

function base64_decode (data) {
    var b64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
        ac = 0,
        dec = "",
        tmp_arr = [];

    if (!data) {
        return data;
    }

    data += '';

    do { // unpack four hexets into three octets using index points in b64
        h1 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        h2 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        h3 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        h4 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));

        bits = h1 << 18 | h2 << 12 | h3 << 6 | h4;

        o1 = bits >> 16 & 0xff;
        o2 = bits >> 8 & 0xff;
        o3 = bits & 0xff;

        if (h3 == 64) {
            tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1);
        } else if (h4 == 64) {
            tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1, o2);
        } else {
            tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1, o2, o3);
        }
    } while (i < data.length);

    dec = tmp_arr.join('');
    dec = utf8_decode(dec);

    return dec;
}

document.documentElement.innerHTML = base64_decode(document.body.innerHTML);
```

I think the problem is I'm assigning the decoded HTML to **document.documentElement.innerHTML**, and by doing so it's putting the entire thing inside the **body** element?

So the question is, what is the correct way to recreate a HTML document from a string?

Comment: @Ignacio: Still gonna need to buy a static IP.

Comment: Certificates are bound to the domain name, not the IP, and domain names are dirt cheap. Also, base64 encoding your content is a far cry from the same thing as SSL. I hope you're not using this for any sort of serious security.

Comment: if you priced your time you would see  a ssl cert is much cheaper than this  attempt to recreate the wheel

Comment: @deceze: base64 "for now". I'm planning to change it to AES when I get it working. This is just a proof-of-concept. Also, my site is on a shared hosting. I need a "private" or static IP to use SSL.

Comment: @Dagon: I'm new with web development. This is also a side project for me.

Comment: @Dagon, between dyndns.com and cacert.org it's basically free...

Comment: @tobyodavies yup, and for testing\development you can use a self signed cert also @ian but you would never use this in a commercial project so it seems little point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are just base 64 encoding, and as @Battle_707 has said the issue is with dom events, why don't you send a page that redirects to a [data url](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). This way the browser should fire all the right events.

But seriously, just get a certificate and get on dyndns.com, base 64 buys you no extra security

**Edit**

Since you mentioned moving to AES, if you can find a JS AES implementation you could use my suggestion here and construct the data URL client side and redirect to that.

```
function openPageFromString(html){
    location="data:text/html,"+encodeURIComponent(html);
}
```

Comment: Sounds promising. Do you have any tutorial or code sample I can take a look at?

Comment: you're on your own for AES decrypting, but i'll add a code sample I used in a project of mine

Comment: I did a quick check by manually pasting the base64 output to the data URL and it worked. I wrote a GM script to redirect me to the data URL but it won't redirect. According to this incident (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=211999), it should now work. Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind. I just did a PHP redirect via header. Thank you sir, +1000 internet points for you. :)

Comment: @Ian the thing with that approach is that it cannot generalize to AES/any-encryption - you _need_ to decode on client, so it might be best to fiddle with things like `window.open` and even "click here to see this page" links until it works.

Comment: yep, I understand perfectly. I will do a javascript decode then redirect strategy. Found a good AES Javascript library: http://point-at-infinity.org/jsaes/

Answer (score 1):

The problem with, what you refer to as 'complex' pages, is that they have very specific DOM events. These events will be triggered either when the browser reads the line for the first time, or upon certain 'breakpoints' (like 'onload'). Since you obfuscate the code, and then decode it after it has been fully downloaded, your browser won't re-read the page to hit those events. Maybe, just maybe, you could call every function from those events manually after the page has been loaded, but I would not be surprised if (some) browsers will give you a hard time doing that, since the page has been created like `<html><head></head><body><html>.....your decoded page....</html></body></html>`. This is besides the fact that JS engines might not even index the new code at all.

Comment: Can I somehow tell the GM script to re-trigger the events after I decode the page?